# Determining when ListView position changes

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

fairly new to Android development and I've got a question I've Google'd the crap out of and can't find a solid answer on.

I simply want to know how to determine when the position in a ListView changes. Specifically, I've got a ListView whose TextView text changes color when I click on it. The problem is, when I click on a different position in the ListView, the color of the text of the position I was just on stays what it was changed to.

Basically, is there a way to listen for a position change in a ListView, and then execute code when that position changes?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Explain your scenario more clearly.

Comment: What do you have coded so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want one item to be selected at a time make sure you set the choice mode to single when you're setting up your ListView.

```
myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)
```

You'll need to set an onItemClickListener.

```
myListView..setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
        // Your Code Here               
        }
    });
```

When you set up your ArrayAdapter you can use one of the default Android item layouts such as `simple_list_item_activated_1`, which highlights the background of the selected item.

```
myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, myArrayList);
```

If you want your own custom behavior such as changing the text color rather than the background, then simply replace the item layout with one of your own. Have a look at the default Android item layouts to see how they write them. For example, below is the default Android item layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1`, where you can see they've used a selector called `activatedBackgroundIndicator` to define the background color.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
/>
```

**`<Additional>`**
In your case, to get the text color to change instead of the background, you will want to use a selector for your text color. Make a `color` folder in your `res` directory. Create a selector in it:

**`my_color_selector.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/my_red_color />
    <item android:drawable="@color/my_blue_color" />  <!-- color when not selected -->
</selector>
```

Then in your custom item layout set the color of your text to `my_color_selector`

Comment: Once I click on one of the ListView items and it changes according to the selector, how do I make it go back to default when I then click on a different ListView item? I've figured out how to remove the highlight from the ListView item and make it go back to what it was before, but I cannot figure out how to make the text color change back.

Comment: Use a selector xml to define your your text color based on state, where they've used a selector to define background color.

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional info. Also, as I said at the start of my answer, setting `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` is vital if you only want one item to be highlighted at a time.

Comment: Thanks! Got me to where I wanted to be... didn't understand drawables at all really... also was able to figure out how to change that highlight color, make it stay when clicked, and change the text color.